# How graduate students get to work in homological mirror symmetry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, gauge-theory, mirror-symmetry

My question is probably an odd one here but I would very much like to work in Homological Mirror Symmetry. An example of a course I'd like to be able to take and understand is [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~jpascale/courses/2018/595/](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ejpascale/courses/2018/595/)

It uses references like “D. Auroux, A beginner's introduction to Fukaya categories” among others and it is exactly the kind of thing you'd expect as a specialty course for graduate students. Here's my problem though:

Some universities I've seen (notably in Hong Kong and Japan) have undergraduate programs that look very standard compared to the American one and they don't seem to have specialty courses usually taken by undergrads but then these students go into a 2 year master's degree and come out with some serious looking theses on mirror symmetry, Calabi-Yau manifolds and Gauge Theory etc. Bear in mind, the programs are shorter there (PhD is like 3 years or 4 at most...not 5 like in the US) so I feel like I'm missing something here.

That Illinois course is almost entirely out of my reach and I've taken a reasonable amount of algebra (up to Fields and Galois Theory), some basic smooth manifold theory (at the level of Loring Tu's  Intro to Manifolds) and a decent amount of the first 3 chapters of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry.

I STILL cannot read Denis Auroux's Fukaya Categories intro and some of the other references so I am seriously wondering what it is these students (in some of the universities I mentioned) are doing that I am not. How are they getting the background required to find these areas of research so accessible?

Any opinions/advice/light shedding would be great.

Comment: Although I didn't do my graduate work in quite as erudite an area as HMS, I still struggled with assimilating background. The thing is that you need to be working with an advisor who can guide you to and through the necessary bits and pieces of various topics that you need to learn.

Comment: How would you rate your comfort with the 4 topics listed as prerequisites on the linked course page? Next, are you attempting this on your own or with others (students/professors)? Finally, if you're a student at a university, have you considered asking faculty there for advice? The basic outline of getting started on math research before you've gotten a PhD is that you'll probably need a mentor to help you out, and I highly encourage you to pursue one.

Comment: You may be overestimating the level of originality in the master's theses you see. Some could be mainly expository.

Comment: @Zhen Lin  You probably are right especially with regards to the Master's theses but they still need to understand that stuff though and the question stands.

Comment: The level of understanding needed to write an expository paper is less than for conducting original research, in my view.

Comment: I am from that HK university specialized in Mirror symmetry: they mastered all the basic stuff (smooth manifolds, algebraic topology, AG, homological algebra) in their undergraduate studies, and work like a PhD when they do a master.

Comment: @Arctic Char In which courses? I looked at the list and I didn't see any of that. The differential geometry course in UG seems to cover mostly classical DG and there didn't seem to be anything that covered AG or Homological Algebra. So maybe there are courses they do that they just don't list online?

Comment: Well they do that on their own.

Comment: @MaryM Keep in mind that much advanced learning is done via reading courses/independent study, and thus will not be part of any course catalog.